Problem with controlling a simple DC motor using PMOSFET and also PNP (Tinkercad)?
Circuit: Tinkercad link
I have been trying to learn about transistors. I understood how to work with NPN and NMOSFET transistors and on the right-hand-side of my project you can see the NMOS demo works as expected.
But for PMOS transistor the dc motor simply slows down. It doesn't stop as intended (as in the NMOS demo). This also happens when I play around with PNP transistors:

This is just for learning purposes, (I am not even an electrical student). I just want to understand why doesn't my pmos circuit work in the same way that my nmos circuit does and what I can do to fix it. My aim is to simply let the motor work then delay then make it stop, delay, and so on and so on...
If you can't access tinkercad for whatever reason here is my circuit:

The right hand side NMOS circuit works as expected while the PMOS does not work (left hand side). I mean the motor just slows down it doesn't actually stop like in the other circuit.
Here is the code:
const int pMosfetPin = 13;
const int nMosfetPin = 9;

void setup() {
  pinMode(pMosfetPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(nMosfetPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // nmos
  digitalWrite(nMosfetPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(nMosfetPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  // pmos
  digitalWrite(pMosfetPin, HIGH);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(pMosfetPin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}


Based on the hard to decipher squiggly wires instead of proper schematics, you are using the PFET as high side switch for the motor.
Without knowing the pinout of the FET you used, there may be two things that might be wrong.

You have FET source and drain terminals swapped, so current flows via the inrinsic diode in the FET so motor always runs

You have source and drain terminals correct, but because there is 9V on source, the MCU controls the gate with 0V and 5V, so Vgs voltage is either 9V or 4V, and the FET is always on.


In other words, if you had an MCU that outputs say 9V and 0V, the PFET would be off when 9V at gate (0V Vgs) and on when 0V at gate (9V Vgs).

You have no idea how grateful I am thanks. I switched the 9V source to a 3V coin battery just to test 2 (I am 100% certain my drain and source terminals are perfectly connected). Everything works now! So the arduino/MCU signal to the pmos should always be more than the supply?

Also peculiar behavior got me curious, if i put a 50 Ohm resistor between the gate and the 9V battery it works but that is just weird...

@MarisaKirisame That's likely to destroy your microcontroller.
